# Why does `std::set::erase(const key_type&)` return `size_type` instead of `bool`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, return-type, stdset, erase-remove-idiom

Because `std::set` doesn't `insert()` duplicates, it's assured to contain unique elements. When using the overload `erase(const key_type&)`, its object would have contained maximum 1 element of that same value. Hence, it may return either 1 (if present) or 0 (otherwise).

When can `erase(const key_type&)` may return more than 1?
In other words, what is the purpose of returning a `size_type` instead of simple `bool`?

Comment: [std::set<Key,Compare,Allocator>::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) **(3)**

Comment: **The erase-remove idiom is a common C++ technique to eliminate elements that fulfill a certain criterion from a C++ Standard Library container.** "Instead of removing elements, remove operator puts elements, that doesn't match criteria, at the end of given range and then returns an iterator pointing one element past the last matching element. Then the erase member function deletes elements from returned iterator to the given one."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of returning `size_type` is consistency; all associative containers have an `erase` method that takes a key type and returns a size. Even if the size can only be zero or one, it's still the same interface.

Comment: Knew about this reason beforehand and forgot to mention in my Qn to rule out that. Basically I wanted to know any other intent apart from this.